# Terraform Cloud - Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Moving to terraform cloud from my local receiving the below message. My codebase is in Gitlab. I presume its supported to reference the file just like I did locally?

> on ../modules/instances/instance.tf line 32, in resource "aws_instance" "server":
> user_data       = file("user-data-server.sh")
> while calling file(path)
> Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "user-data-server.sh"; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.

My terraform file code references file as:

```
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  ami           = var.aws_ami_id
  subnet_id     = "${element(var.public_subnet.*.id, 3)}"
  key_name      = var.ec2_key_pair
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.aws_security_group.main-sg.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data       = file("user-data-server.sh")

  tags = {
    Name = "Server"
  }
}
```

The file user-data-server.sh is in the same directory as this terraform script.

Comment: How about `user_data = file("${path.root}/user-data-server.sh")`?

Comment: Pretty much the same:
while calling file(path)
path.root is "."
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "./user-data-server.sh"; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.

Comment: Ah, ok, so I didn't pay attention it was in the module. How about `user_data = file("${path.module}/user-data-server.sh")`?

Comment: @MarkoE You are spot on, thanks! Working now as expected, I did originally try path.root but didn't think about trying path.module. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkoE Can you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error that is displayed, terraform cannot find the script at the location specified. Since a module is used to create the EC2 instance, and the path to the file specified is as if it were inside of the same directory where the root module is stored, that has caused the error. To help with that, terraform has [several built-in options](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info), one of which is `path.module`:

> `path.module` is the filesystem path of the module where the expression is placed. We do not recommend using `path.module` in write operations because it can produce different behavior depending on whether you use remote or local module sources. Multiple invocations of local modules use the same source directory, overwriting the data in `path.module` during each call. This can lead to race conditions and unexpected results.

To fix the error from the question, this should help:

```
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  ami           = var.aws_ami_id
  subnet_id     = "${element(var.public_subnet.*.id, 3)}"
  key_name      = var.ec2_key_pair
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.aws_security_group.main-sg.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data       = file("${path.module}/user-data-server.sh")
  tags = {
    Name = "Server"
  }
}
```